# python Stacked area chart Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh, stacked

I am trying to create a stacked area chart, which shows the number of customers by country.

So my data frame is:

```
date        people  country
2021-11-18  509     USA
2021-11-18  289     France 
2021-11-18  234     Germany
2021-11-18  148     Poland
2021-11-18  101     China
```

I don't understand how to edit the graphic design (color).

```
table.groupby(['date','country'])['people'].sum().unstack().plot(
    kind='area',
    figsize=(10,4))
```

[image: actual output]

Also I tried to use the Bokeh library for nice visualization, but i don't know how to write the code

Thanks for your help. It's my first post. Sorry if I missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your are looking for [`varea_stack()`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting/figure.html?highlight=stack#bokeh.plotting.Figure.varea_stack)-function in `bokeh`.

My solution is based on the [`varea_stack`-example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/stacked_area.html) which is part of the official documentation.

Let's assume this is your data (I added on day):

```python
text = """date        people  country
2021-11-18  509     USA
2021-11-18  289     France 
2021-11-18  234     Germany
2021-11-18  148     Poland
2021-11-18  101     China
2021-11-19  409     USA
2021-11-19  389     France 
2021-11-19  134     Germany
2021-11-19  158     Poland
2021-11-19  191     China"""
```

First I bring the data in the same form of the example:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), sep='\s+', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)

df = df.groupby(['date','country']).sum().unstack()
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
df.index.name=None
df.columns.name=None
```

Now the DataFrame looks like this:

```
            China  France  Germany  Poland  USA
2021-11-18    101     289      234     148  509
2021-11-19    191     389      134     158  409
```

Now the rest is straight forward. If your index is a `DatetimeIndex` you have to modify the `x_axis_type` of the bokeh figure. Id did this for the plot below.

```
from bokeh.palettes import brewer
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

n = df.shape[1]
p = figure(x_axis_type='datetime')
p.varea_stack(stackers=df.columns, x='index', source=df, color=brewer['Spectral'][n],)
show(p)
```

The output lookslike this:

[image: varea-stack withd DatetimeIndex]

You can redefine the color using the `color`-keyword if you like.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried to apply the code, I get an error: 'KeyError: 516'

Comment: Can you post more information? This error is unkown to me and it looks like it is unreleated to this minimal example.

Comment: of course, add info: 
BokehJS 2.4.1 successfully loaded.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-cc76834eee5c> in <module>
      5 n = df.shape[1]
      6 p = figure(x_axis_type='datetime')
----> 7 p.varea_stack(stackers=df.columns, x='index', source=df, color=brewer['Spectral'][n],)
      8 show(p)

KeyError: 516

Comment: Is your DataFrame available? Can you try to run the bokeh example from the documentation? Do you get the same error?

Comment: the example from the documentation works correctly

Comment: What is the type of your `date` column? I edited my post, so you can read in the data as I did. I hope this now runs without error.

Comment: swapped df = table.groupby(['partner','date']).sum().unstack()    and now got another error: ----> 7 p.varea_stack(stackers=df.columns, x='index', source=df, color=brewer['Spectral'][n],)
      8 show(p)

KeyError: 20

Comment: Could you please update your qustion with your data?

Comment: there are no such characters in the data

Comment: How many columns do have? I think `brewer['Spectral']` is to short and you need a longer list. I think this list has a maximum of 20 elements. Find your value `n` and check id `brewer['Spectral'][n]`  raises this error.

Comment: 516 rows × 20 columns. tryinf using upper recomendation

Comment: You could try color = brewer['Spectral'][10]+brewer['Spectral'][10]. This uses each color twice. Also you could create your own list with 20 HEX-color tags like #555555. To check if the problem is this line, you can also remove the color, then it uses only one color

Comment: I checked the length of `brewer['Spectral']`. The longest list is 11. When you have 20 values, then you can create a list with 20 values like this: `brewer['Spectral'][11]+ brewer['BuGn'][9]`

Answer (score 0):

you should add colors to your source or you could use color pallettes in bokeh. please check [here](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#stacking).